# currently proccesed file name-informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter

The currently processed file name is loading till the path of the file and not the file name.
It is showing no error when executing the workflow.
can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: check the length of the column

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response samik.

The ports were not aligned properly, since they have same data type it got executed without error but the data got truncated. Now its loading the file name after arranging them.